# VB.NET Search ListBox for string and return specific data

Tags: vb.net, search, listbox

I have a populated listbox. Each item has a string of data with id's and values. How would i search for the id and receive the vale?

If i search for 'itemColor' i would like it to return each boot color in a new msgbox.

```
itemName="boots" itemCost="$39" itemColor="red"
itemName="boots" itemCost="$39" itemColor="green"
itemName="boots" itemCost="$39" itemColor="blue"
itemName="boots" itemCost="$39" itemColor="yellow"
```

I understand there are different and easier ways to do this but i need to do it this way.

Thanks!

Comment: Search the `ListBox` source (if, hopefully, you're using a searchable data source). [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) helps a lot here anyway.

Comment: As a small tip and pointing you towards the answer by @Mary .. It looks like you're using the listbox as your primary way of storing your data. Using controls as data storage isn't a good idea for several reason. It will slow your program down, and in certain cases, the data could be changed by users when you dont want it to be - mary's answer will give you the essentials. From there I would thoroughly recommend finding more detail about what you can do with lists and listboxes such as databinding. You'll be a better programmer for it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it involving parsing the text as XML:

```
' Here's Some Sample Text
Dim listboxText As String = "itemName=""boots"" itemCost=""$39"" itemColor=""red"""

' Load XML and Convert to an Object
Dim xmlDocument As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
xmlDocument.LoadXml("<item " & listboxText & "></item>")
Dim item = New With {.ItemName = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes("itemName").Value,
        .ItemCost = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes("itemCost").Value,
        .ItemColor = xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes("itemColor").Value}

' Write It Out as a Test
Console.WriteLine(item.ItemName & " " & item.ItemCost & item.ItemColor)
Console.Read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class (or structure), the appropriate properties, a default constructor, a parametized constructor and an Override of .ToString.

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Cost As String
    Public Property Color As String
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(sName As String, sCost As String, sColor As String)
        Name = sName
        Cost = sCost
        Color = sColor
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return $"{Name} - {Cost} - {Color}"
    End Function
End Class
```

Item objects are added to the list box calling the parameterized constructor. The list box calls .ToString on the objects to determine what to display.

```
Private Sub FillList()
    ListBox3.Items.Add(New Item("boots", "$39", "red"))
    ListBox3.Items.Add(New Item("boots", "$39", "green"))
    ListBox3.Items.Add(New Item("boots", "$39", "blue"))
    ListBox3.Items.Add(New Item("boots", "$39", "yellow"))
End Sub
```

Since we added Item objects to the list box, we can cast each list item back to the Item type and access its properties.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    For Each i In ListBox3.Items
        sb.AppendLine(DirectCast(i, Item).Color)
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString)
End Sub
```